# PHP max execution time

Tags: php

Is it going to be a strain on my server if I am using PHP scripts to download a file while the file is very large, and it takes around 4 minutes to download it via PHP. Currently I'm executing the script in the browser, but when I switch to my linux server it will be executed via the shell. Right now I have put this in my script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000);
```

Are there any negative factors to using **ini_set** I should be aware of when it takes quite a bit of time for a PHP script to execute because it is download a large .ZIP file? Should I have to worry about memory leaks?

Comment: Please be aware that this changes the max execution time of php only.  The webserver may be set to terminate any process at it's own interval.  As for negative factors... not really, unless you have out of control scripts that would include memory leaks or such.

Comment: PHP's cpu usage while serving up a file will be fairly minimal compared to the I/O required. You can always monitor CPU usage while the download is progressing (task manager on windows, 'top' on unix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just sending the file in one large chunk, why not split it up into lots of little chunks. The benefit of that is it stops php from timing out & lets you download larger files.

Take a look at this tutorial for more info http://teddy.fr/blog/how-serve-big-files-through-php

Comment: I'm downloading the file from a remote server. It is one XML file zipped up.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20120309172643/http://teddy.fr/blog/how-serve-big-files-through-php